# Powershell script: get multiple properties from "Get-Childitem" in a loop

Tags: powershell

i am absolutely not a programmer, so please excuse my ignorance and clumsy code.

My task is to change one value per file with 1.25*value in a number of xml-files in a folder.

I have come up with the following code which seems to go through all files and changes each value correctly, then writes the new changed files to a new subfolder "DD1". My test code so far only wrote to a single file test.xml all the time, overwriting it per each loop.

I want the altered files to be named exactly like the original ones, so i am trying to grab each filename within the loop but so far to no avail. Maybe you can tell me, what to put instead of the "????????"

```
New-Item '.\DD1'  -ItemType Directory

Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.pws |

Foreach-Object {
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content $_.FullName
$valueString = $myXML.settings.TuningMenu.FF
$valueInt = [int]$valueString
$newValueInt = $valueInt*1.25
$newValueString = [string]$newValueInt
$myXML.settings.TuningMenu.FF = $newValueString
[string]$path = $PWD
[string]$file = ????????
$fullName = $path+"\DD1\"+$file
$myXML.Save("$fullName")
}
```

Comment: `[string]$file = $_.Name`?

Comment: `$fullName = '{0}\DD1\{1}' -f $_.DirectoryName , $_.Name ; $myXML.Save($fullName)`